# How to get last update Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

How to get time last status update on Twitter ? use python and tweepy

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the commands that I used to read tweets from my personal Twitter account using Python. I hope you can use the same to read the last status update from Twitter.

```
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"
consumer_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY"
consumer_secret = "ENTER YOUR API SECRET"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    print data
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

#This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python'
stream.filter(track=['python'])
```